# Tibco EMS with Tomcat configuration

Tags: spring, tomcat7, jndi, tibco-ems

I searched for and answer before posting, but didn't find a solution. If I missed it please link me to it.

Here is my problem. I'm trying to use jndi to connect my tibco server.

Right now I have my resource tag setup inside my tomcat server.xml file:

```
<Resource name="tibcoConnection" 
   auth="Container"
   type="com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory"
   factory="com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsObjectFactory"
   severUrl=<tibcourl>
   userName=xxxxxxx
   password=xxxxxxx />
```

For the factory I originally had com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmConnectionFactory but tomcat threw an error cast it to ObjectFactory. So I changed it.

I have my ResourceLink tag in context.xml pointing to the tibcoConnectoin name and type com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory.

My Spring bean is `<jee:jndi-lookup id="tibco" jndi-name="tibcoConnection"/>`

I'm using the connection for:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
   <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="tibco"/>
</bean>
```

I my logs I'm getting a `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [tibco] is not bound in the Context. Unable to find [tibco]`

I'm lost since there isn't much documentation out there for tomcat and tibco that I could find. If anyone has had any luck with configuring tomcat with tibco and spring, please help.

Comment: have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: No I have not. I moved past this problem and will come back to it if need be. Still would like a solution if someone happens to have one.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the issue might be that you define your resource name as `"tibcoConnectoin"` ("o" before "i"), but you refer to it in your jndi-lookup as `"tibcoConnection"` ("o" after "i")?

Comment: No that was just a typo here. I'll correct the question